# Why closure return type definition must include '_ lifetime?

Tags: rust

The `concatenator_using` function produces closure that can be used to concatenate strings inside `fold` function. I've got it to work, but I don't understand why `String + '_` is required in closure return type instead of just `String`. Actually I don't understand what `'_` means or refers to. Substituting it with `'a` causes `undeclared lifetime` compilation error.

```
fn main() {
    assert_eq!("d|e|f", vec!["d", "e", "f"].iter().fold(String::new(), concatenator_using("|")));
}

fn concatenator_using(delimiter: &str) -> impl Fn(String, &&str) -> String + '_ {
    |mut acc: String, i: &&str| {
        if !acc.is_empty() {
            acc.push_str(delimiter);
        }
        acc.push_str(i);
        acc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime is not part of the return type of the `Fn()` trait; instead, it's a separate trait bound in addition to the `Fn()` bound. Stated differently, the return type of `concatenator_using()` should be read as – note the additional parentheses –

```
impl (Fn(String, &&str) -> String) + '_
```

The `concatenator_using` function returns a type implementing the trait `Fn(String, &&str) -> String` with the lifetime `'_` (see more about this lifetime below).

The expression `String + '_` does not make any sense in Rust. You can use the plus operator to require multiple trait or lifetime bounds, so you can write `T: Trait1 + Trait2 + 'a + 'b` to state that a generic type `T` must implement both these traits and be valid for both these lifetimes. However, `String` is a concrete type, not a trait, so `String + '_` is meaningless.

An abstract return type specified as `impl Trait` is by default treated as having static lifetime, so it is equivalent to `impl Trait + 'static`. In your code, the returned closure does not have static lifetime, so you get an error message when not specifying a lifetime for the abstract return type at all. Specifying a lifetime of `'_` adds a free lifetime parameter to the abstract return type, which is inferred according to Rust's usual lifetime elision rules. In this case, there is only a single implicit lifetime in the function arguments, so the free lifetime parameter in the return type is identified with the implicit lifetime parameter in the `delimiter` argument. If you want to explicitly specify the lifetime parameters instead of letting Rust infer them, you can write

```
fn concatenator_using<'a>(delimiter: &'a str) -> impl Fn(String, &&str) -> String + 'a
```

to specify that the lifetime of the returned closure corresponds to the lifetime of the `delimiter` parameter.

Comment: Thank you Sven. I've read about Lifetime Elision at https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html#lifetime-elision but from what I understood, elision means that we remove the lifetime from signature so I'm still a bit unsure why that `+'_` is still required.

Comment: It's required because the default lifetime of `impl Trait` is static, and the lifetime of the object you return is not. Adding `'_` introduces a free lifetime parameter into the return type, i.e. a lifetime that has not been specified. The elision rules now see a single (implicit) free lifetime parameter in the arguments and a single (explicit) free lifetime parameter in the return type, so these two lifetimes are identified.

Comment: I realize I'm just restating what I said in my answer, but I don't know what point specifically is unclear to you.

Comment: Oh, now I see that `'_` is to override the default `'static` lifetime. I thought that the default would be to take lifetime of param. Thank you.